# OPENVPN: MULTI: bad source address from client

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I struggled this problem for two days, but the problem is still here. Hope someone can provide suggestion or the way how to diagnose it.

What i want is let all client visit Internet over the OpenVPN server. Therefore, I first follow instructions [Routing all client traffic (including web-traffic) through the VPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html). After configuration, and setup iptables, the connection between VPN server and client succeeds, but the client can not visit any website (the brower is hang there). The `ping` from server and client are OK.

I checked log at the server, and there are some records like:

```
   Oct  3 09:16:21 iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z ovpn-delta[1827]: laptop/131.202.XX.XX:59701 UDPv4 READ [93] from [AF_INET]131.202.XX.XX:59701: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=92
    Oct  3 09:16:21 iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z ovpn-delta[1827]: laptop/131.202.XX.XX:59701 MULTI: bad source address from client [131.202.XX.XX], packet dropped
```

where the IP: 131.202.XX.XX is my laptop IP address. This record is explained in ["MULTI: bad source address from client , packet dropped" or "GET INST BY VIRT: [failed]"](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/317-qmulti-bad-source-address-from-client--packet-droppedq-or-qget-inst-by-virt-failedq.html), why this IP is not 10.8.0.6 (tun0) at my laptop, and the detail implementation for the problem? My laptop connects to Internet using WIFI, and it is a device that runs `openvpn --config client.conf`.

As this is very simple example, Do I have a way to avoid this error, or any sample to config `client-config-dir and create a ccd file`

the `/etc/openvpn/delta.conf` at the server:

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

;dev-node MyTap

ca ca.crt
cert delta.crt
key delta.key  # This file should be kept secret

dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

;server-bridge

;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
;learn-address ./script

;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"

;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

keepalive 10 120

;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES
comp-lzo
;max-clients 100
;user nobody
;group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
;mute 20
```

while the `client.conf` is:

```
   client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 116.62.193.49 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194
;remote-random

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert laptop.crt
key laptop.key
ns-cert-type server

;tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo

verb 3
;mute 20
```

For IP router configuration, I added the iptables to `/etc/rc.local`, so that iptables can be changed at server startup.

```
root@iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z:/var/log# cat /etc/rc.local 
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#I also tried comment out first three instructions, but still does not work 
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

service dnsmasq restart

exit 0
```

and the `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

---

`telnet serverIP 80` is OK. In the server: /var/logs/syslog:

Is there any solution?

Comment: I don't have that line forcing dns to the server in my config, and I can see that causing problems with dns resolution. Have you tried with that line commented out? I push opendns servers to the clients.

Comment: @OrganicMarble. It does not work with the same error message, when I comment out `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"` and push openDNS. The only works when I comment out both `push "redirect-gateway def1"` and DNS push operation. But this is not what I expect

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` show on your laptop when you are connected to the vpn. Can you post the routing tables too `netstat -rnv`

Comment: @shijiexu what is your output when you run the command `ufw status`?

Comment: thanks @NateT, this post is obsolete,  and I switched a new computer, and use a commercial VPN now.